# How to get the Value of Combo Box_2 So that i can run it in the processing-runalgorithm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using Qgis version 2.18.20
I am making a plugin for split the shp files from a vector layer.

My Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 SplitLayer
                                 A QGIS plugin
 this will split the layer ad saves in the desired folder
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2018-06-25
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2018 by Goku_Force
        email                : 160303105162@paruluniversity.ac.in
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon ,QFileDialog,QWidget
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsPoint
# Import the code for the dialog
from split_layer_dialog import SplitLayerDialog
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox
import os.path


class SplitLayer:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.
        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """

        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'SplitLayer_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = SplitLayerDialog()


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&split layer')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'SplitLayer')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'SplitLayer')
        self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)


    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('SplitLayer', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        #self.dlg = SplitLayerDialog()

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/SplitLayer/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u''),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&split layer'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar



    def select_output_file(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file ","", '*.txt')
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)



    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        """layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        layer_list = []
        for layer in layers:
                layer_list.append(layer.name())

        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)"""


        layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        layer_list = []
        for layer in layers:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())
        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
        ##################################################################

        myfilepath=iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
        path_slicing=int(myfilepath.find("."))
        f_path=myfilepath[:path_slicing]
        layer =QgsVectorLayer(f_path+".shp", "Goku_Force", "ogr")
        features = layer.getFeatures()
        f = features.next()
        Id=[str(c.name()) for c in f.fields().toList()]
        #for layer in Id:
        #    layer_list.append(int(Id[layer])
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(Id)



        def field_select():
            self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
            selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
            selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
            fields = [field.name() for field in selectedLayer.pendingFields()]
            self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(fields)

        self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(field_select)

        def field_select_2():
            btt=self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentText()

        self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(field_select_2)




        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
            output_file = open(filename, 'w')

            selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
            selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
            fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
            fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]

            for f in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
                line = ','.join(unicode(f[x]) for x in fieldnames) + '\n'
                unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
                output_file.write(unicode_line)
            output_file.close()
```

---

I want a way to store the current combo box-2 value in a variable that(i.e unique id or field attributes ) i want to use in 
processing.runalg('qgis:splitvectorlayer', input, **field**, output)

I have the value of input 
And i also do not know how to make a select folder i have made a select file for attribute features.

I hope this much information is enough ..
[image: My Plugin design]
[image: Want the Folder Select option To store the Shp file after the spliting algo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add these two lines in the init function

```
self.dlg.lineEdit_2.clear()
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)
self.dlg.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file_1)
```

This is the Syntax for creating a folder dialog box from which the user can select

```
def select_output_file(self):
        self.dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dlg, "Open Directory","",QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly or QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(self.dir)
```

These is the code for selecting the Combox_2 with the index.

```
splitlayer_2=self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentIndex()
splitlayer_1=SplitLayer.Id[splitlayer_2]
SplitLayer1=splitlayer_1
```